# Solr not returning the result on new publishing target based CD

Tags: solr, sitecore-search

We are trying to get the data from one of the custom indexes and the data comes on `CM` and `CD` (web DB based) but we have created a new CD based on the new publishing target as a `preview` and there data doesn't come from the same index.

I checked the solr query in the logs, everywhere the query is the same on `preview`, `cm`, and `cd` (web). But when we load the data on `preview` cd then it does not return the data for the same query.

We have completely published the site on `preview` target.

We checked that data is also available in our custom index (obviously it should be there because it comes on `cm` and `cd` web but thought to check as I am stuck). So not sure why isn't it coming for the new `preview`.

Below is the query:

```
Solr Query - ?q=(((((((_path:(2ded2b03fsdfsg4cd2a46719ee) AND _template:(f7b5c470bsadfsg817bd9ac14af)) AND product_capabilities_sm:(0da4c6372aFSDF9ceddb77af3)) AND _latestversion:("True")) AND (has_country_restrictions_b:("False") OR country_availability_sm:(41239aSADFF38683cf83b7))) AND ((_path:("c83165SDFSDF9018d1b6cb4f") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("fbdc2262a61a4SDFSD4a22d720") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("00b9edfdFDSF7eb52c67") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("a41bbe42fedd4asdsc6a10f") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("685c0cdee82dsdsde6000f2a1fb") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("c609e8ddsfsf9b1aee4f23") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("a397f54d7sdsdcb067c016b7fe") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("21b82c37d18b4sdsdbd7e43") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("738c74fe88bc43sdsd3517281b6815") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("ca63b9343sdsde71f4419") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("27c198172dsdsd609df0d608b") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("190fae814e7b445dbb4fe771a6946d16") AND searchable_b:("True")) OR (_path:("b240656ffaasdsdd5d3e684") AND searchable_b:("True")))) AND _language:("en")) AND _latestversion:("True")) AND _val_:__boost&start=0&rows=0&fq=(((-_readaccess:("U-_extranet\\Anonymous") *:*) AND ((-_readaccess:("R-_sitecore\\Coveo Configuration Admin") *:*) OR _readaccess:("U+_extranet\\Anonymous"))) AND (((-_readaccess:("R-_Everyone") *:*) AND (-_readaccess:("R-_extranet\\Everyone") *:*)) OR _readaccess:("R+_sitecore\\Coveo Configuration Admin") OR _readaccess:("U+_extranet\\Anonymous")))&fq=_indexname:(sitecore_taxes_web_index)&facet=true&facet.field=taxonomy_industry_name_list_sm&f.taxonomy_industry_name_list_sm.facet.mincount=1&facet.field=product_group_name_list_sm&f.product_group_name_list_sm.facet.mincount=1&facet.field=is_sustainable_application_b&f.is_sustainable_application_b.facet.mincount=1&facet.field=has_autonomy_b&f.has_autonomy_b.facet.mincount=1&wt=xml
```

Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot the query environment specific, to know why query behaves fine on `cd` web but not on the cd `preview`?

**Update-1:**
I checked that `var i = searchContext.GetQueryable<CapabilityProductMappingSearchResultItem>();` line is not giving the result for the new `CD` but the same give to `cd` web. This code created the search context on the same index used for `cd` web and new publishing target based `cd`.

```
[PredefinedQuery("TemplateId", ComparisonType.Equal, "1245f04e-1758-4e94-a8eb-d90e433f750c", typeof(ID))]
    public class CapabilityProductMappingSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
    {
        [IndexField("capability_sm")]
        public List<Guid> Capability { get; set; }

        [IndexField("product_group_sm")]
        public List<Guid> ProductGroup { get; set; }

        [IndexField("products_sm")]
        public List<Guid> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it definitely the exact same SOLR end point and Core being targeted? If the same query is being generated, then the same response should be returned from SOLR. Try changing the "web" connection string on your preview instance to point to the same web db from your CD instance. If that fixes the problem, then some item or template ma not have been published that the view relies on?

Comment: @DeanOBrien I have updated my question to provide more context based on the investigation that I did, maybe that can help.

Comment: Hi Prashant, In your query, I see 'fq=_indexname:(sitecore_taxes_web_index)'. It seems your code is calling web indexes instead of preview.

Comment: @VikrantPunwatkar We have kept it deliberately according to client requirements but the question is that same index works for cm and cd (web) but why not for cd (preview)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have further done the RCA and found that

1. when we are reading the index on the publishing target then it is reading the web index because in the site settings item, the `Database` field had the `web` DB selected, and due to the code `sitecore_custom_{sitecore.context.database.name}_index` it was coming as (`sitecore_custom_web_index`) and in the SOLR query it includes a predicate like `fq=_indexname:(sitecore_custom_web_index)`.
2. I checked the returned data on the SOLR portal and then noticed that there is one field `_indexname` that includes the name of the index and this value is the name of the core mentioned for your index.
3. When we were reading the data with the web index on the new publishing target based cd I also noticed that in the project the web index was patched with the preview's index's core name and `fq` was sending the name of the `web` index as `fq=_indexname:(sitecore_custom_web_index)` but the web index is patched with preview's core, so the documents returned are having the `_indexname` field to be `sitecore_custom_preview_index`.
4. Therefore, while reading the web index, `fq` is passing the `_indexname:(sitecore_custom_web_index)` but the core is `sitecore_custom_preview_index` so documents returned as part of the query has the `_indexname` as `sitecore_custom_preview_index` so this is not matching as per the SOLR query generated, and the count is not same as should have been with web.

Now to resolve this we can modify the `fq` to send the `_indexname` to be the core name (`sitecore_custom_preview_index`) instead of `_indexname` (`sitecore_custom_web_index`). But, this is not possible as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38571353/clear-all-filterquery-in-sitecore-contentsearch-linq-query

So, we are now making the new preview's context change to preview, by selecting the `preview` DB in the site setting item' `Database` field so that `_indexname` can be passed as  (`sitecore_custom_preview_index`) instead of `_indexname` (`sitecore_custom_web_index`)